# How can I override the reminder time on appointments when the sender doesn't set one?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2003

Some folks in my office don't like Outlook reminders and send meeting invitations without the reminder flag set.  I often forget to override this setting when accepting the meeting request and consequently forget to attend the meeting.  **Is there a way to force Outlook to assign my preferred reminder time (15 minutes) on all incoming requests that don't have the reminder flag set?**  Overriding all incoming reminder flags (i.e. the nuclear option) is also acceptable.

<rhetorical>What kind of dumb calendar system prefers the sender's reminder flag over the user's?</rhetorical>

Edit:  A Google search found [this script](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/resources/qanda/feb08/hey0221.mspx) that can force reminders on existing appointments.  However, it would need to be run daily (or more) to be effective.  I would prefer a setting or registry change that makes the functionality automatic.

Edit2: Outlook-2003

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked into Tools > Rules and Alerts?

There's an option to run a script after a message has arrived and you can set up a rule to check meeting invitations. Set it up to run the script you found.

See this [Microsoft support page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306108) for how to create scripts

Comment: I see the rule but how do I install the script.. the script field is an empty drop down list.