# How do I add custom scripts to Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2003

I need to add a custom script to process Outlook meeting requests.  ([see this question](https://superuser.com/questions/49608/how-can-i-override-the-reminder-time-on-appointments-when-the-sender-doesnt-set))
The dropdown menu for selecting scripts is empty and there doesn't appear to be a way to add scripts.  **How can I add a script that will be available via Outlook's rules?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Outlook go to Tools > Macro > visual Basic Editor

R-click on Project 1 and select Insert > Module

In Module1 add the following code:

```
Sub CustomMeetingRequestRule(Item As Outlook.MeetingItem)
    If Item.ReminderSet = False Then  
        Item.GetAssociatedAppointment(False).ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 15 
    End If
End Sub
```

Click on Save

Make your rule and the script should appear as a selection when you click on the 'a script' link.

The code should perform what you were after in your other question but haven't tested it.

Reference link: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306108

Comment: I'm getting a popup error message on the script.  Compile error: Argument not optional - with highlighted text ".GetAssociatedAppointment"

Comment: Should have tested :)
How about the following between Sub and End Sub?
If Item.ReminderSet = False Then           Item.GetAssociatedAppointment(False).ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 15
End If
This should set any appointment without a reminder with a 15 min reminder. If you want to set all meeting requests you receive to 15 min reminder then remove the If and End if lines

Comment: Modified code in answer

Answer (score 2):

Scripts in Outlook are also known as macros. I believe Alt+F11 will bring up the VBA script editor for Outlook macros.

Comment: Yes, alt-F11 works but I believe you have to use it from an open e-mail message.. Also you can use File/Options/Customize Ribbon and enable Developer if that option is not already in the ribbon.